# I have created multiples subnets with a loop, how do I obtain the subnet from these resources?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I created multiples subnets with a loop

Now I want to refer the subnet_id from some of them form my nics resources
How to call them ?

trying to do something like this : azurerm_subnet.sub[1].id

The error is below:

> The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
> An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric
> index.

Variables:

```
    vnet = [
    {
        subnet = "10.1.2.0/24"
        name = "TEST"        
    },
    {
        subnet = "10.1.3.0/25"
        name = "TEST2"        
    },
    {
        subnet = "10.1.3.128/25"
        name = "TEST4"        
    }        
]
```

subnet resource :

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = { for subnets in var.vnet : subnets.name => subnets }
  name                 = "SUBNET-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_fw.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet]
}
```

nic resource:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "int" {
  count = 2
  enable_accelerated_networking = false
  enable_ip_forwarding          = false
  location                      = var.location
  name                          = lower("nic-${count.index}")
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig0"
    primary                       = true
    private_ip_address            = "var.ip"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address_version    = "IPv4"
   subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[1].id
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve `TEST2` `subnet.id`.

Comment: Can you share the code so that the community can help you in solving the issue.

Comment: You cannot mix `for_each` and `count` meta-arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform For\_Each: How to reference created resource ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658960/terraform-for-each-how-to-reference-created-resource-id)

Answer (score 0):

This can be you terraform subnet block configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = { for each in var.subnets_config : each.name => each }
  name                  = "Subnet_${each.value.name}"
  address_prefixes      = "${each.value.subnet}"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_fw.name
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did it go? Did you have any new error?

Answer (score -1):

the answer is :values(azurerm_subnet.subnet)[1].id